# A better way to handle set/removeAttribute and adding classList in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've created a custom accordion - full working view on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-brook-wq1vz)

Here's my `handleClick` function for when you click on each of the accordion. I needed an animation (when opening and closing the content) so this is what I tried. I'm not sure this is a React way to approach what I want to achieve.

Any suggestions on how to make this function more React-y?

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const accordion = e.target.parentNode;
    const content = accordion.querySelector(".content");

    if (accordion.hasAttribute("open")) {
      content.style.removeProperty("max-height");
      content.classList.add("closed");
      setTimeout(() => {
        accordion.removeAttribute("open");
      }, 400);
      return;
    }
    // If the <details> element is closed, add the [open] attribute (so the content will render), and animate in
    accordion.setAttribute("open", "");
    // Get proper max-height for element for better animation
    if (!content.getAttribute("data-height")) {
      content.style.maxHeight = "none";
      content.setAttribute(
        "data-height",
        `${content.getBoundingClientRect().height}px`
      );
      content.style.removeProperty("max-height");
    }
    // Wait for the browser to apply [open] to <details>, then animate
    setTimeout(() => {
      content.classList.remove(["closed"]);
      content.style.maxHeight = content.getAttribute("data-height");
    }, 0);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting attributes by selector, I would recommend to use states and interpret those states in the render method such as :

```
  const [accordionOpened, setAccordionOpened] = useState(false);
```

Which will represent by a boolean if the accordion is open or closed.

Since you have multiples items in your accordion, this is not something you want because you will have to duplicate this state for the number of items in the accordion.

I would add a field in your data item such as :

```
 {
   title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pretium sagittis quam vitae commodo. Nulla et ligula non nunc ornare consectetur.",
   opened: false,
 }
```

Which will be interpreted in render method like :

```
{item.opened ? <p className={"openedContent"}>{item.content}</p> : null}
```

And then you will be able to get rid of those extraneous closed and open attributes that are set in the handleClick

Answer (score 0):

In React, you never directly update the UI. Instead, you update the state, then you tell React how to map that state to UI.

Consider breaking the accordion into two components — an `Accordion` and an `AccordionItem`. Then, you have a structure like this:

```
const AccordionItem = ({ title, content, toggle, open }) => (
  <details open={open} onClick={toggle}>
    <summary>{title}</summary>
    <p>{content}</p>
  </details>
);

export const Accordion = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(
    props.items.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      open: false
    }))
  );

  const toggleItem = (idx) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setItems([
      ...items.slice(0, idx),
      { ...items[idx], open: !items[idx].open },
      ...items.slice(idx + 1)
    ]);
  };

  return items.map((item, idx) => (
    <AccordionItem key={idx} toggle={toggleItem(idx)} {...item} />
  ));
};
```

`className` or other attributes could then be set with something like `className={open ? 'is-open' : 'is-closed'}`.

For things like `getBoundingClientRect`, you'd need to use the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), but there are plenty of articles about how to use refs in React, so I won't detail it here.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-8gvym?file=/src/Accordion.js)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm tried your example and tried adding my animation when opening and closing - it's not working. I tried various ways but can't reproduce the animation. What am I doing wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-forked-ode31